# Пауза перед каждым открытием вкладки

Tags: javascript, html

Имею вот такой небольшой код. И объект с ссылками

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var link = items[i].item_id;

  setInterval(function() {
    window.open(link);
  }, 10000);
}
```

Хотелось бы,чтобы открылся item[0],а через 10 секунд item[0+1];

### ГОТОВО РЕШЕНИЕ

Всем конечно спасибо за ваши решения данной проблемы,только уж слишком они сложны для решения такой простой задачи и не повторяются по циклу.
Покапавшись,я сделал всё сам,по-моему оно самое оптимальное.
Всем моим требованиям удоволетворяет.А именно:
1.Открытие ссылок спустя определённое время.
2.Повтор по завершении.
Вот берите,вдруг кому будет надо)

```js
var items = ["vk,com", "twitter,com", "dojki,com", "ya,ru", "google"];

function open() {
  var i = 0;
  var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    window.open(items[i]);
    i++;
    if (i == 5) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// вызов
open();
```

Comment: если вы нашли ответ сами - опубликуйте его как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), например написав функцию которая возвращает promise, который разрешается через определенный интервал, и затем выполнить нужные действия.

Например:

```js
function delay(interval) {
  return new Promise(function(r) {
    setTimeout(r, interval);
  });
}
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var r = items.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  return acc.then(function() {
    return delay(1000).then(function(){
      document.write(cur);
    });
  });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Вот большое спасибо тебе ! Хороший человек.
То что нужно ! )

Ещё вопросик,чтобы повторять циклично надо просто обернуть его в бесконечный цикл while(true)? Или с таким подходом могут быть ошибки.?

Comment: @ThreegunD, то есть бесконечно нужно открывать?

Comment: да,у меня просто есть ещё второй скрипт,он кое-что проверяет и закрывает вкладку через window.close().
так вот надо чтобы открывало бесконечно по кругу.

Comment: @ThreegunD, если набор адресов одинаковый - зачем закрывать?

Comment: разный конечно)

Comment: @ Grundy не подскажешь,как зациклить? при обёртывании в бесконечный цикл он пытается открыть бесконечно количество нулевых элементов,а после,наверное бесконечно количество первых)

Answer (score 0):

Не сетинтервал, а сеттаймаут, интервал будет работать до бесконечности, пока его не прервать.

```js
$(function() {
var d = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  ++d;
  $('#res').text($('#res').text() + '' + d);
 }, 1000 * i);
 console.log('i=' + i)
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Но в вашем коде при выполнении его(то есть когда выводится"="),i всегда равно 10.
А хотелось бы при первом выводе i=0(ну или 1) а при следующем i+1

Comment: @ThreegunD гляньте в консоль, i всегда не равно десяти.

Comment: @ Jean-Claude так я и глянул,
сделал $('#res').text($('#res').text() + '= + i');
и он выдавал мне =10 десять раз)

Comment: @ThreegunD подправил

Comment: @ Jean-Claude 
И тебе большое спасибо за помощь.
Хорошо ,что есть такие как вы)